# Update Linked Excel Slide in Powerpoint Slide Show

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint presentation that needs to loop continuously in order to constantly display information.  I want the linked Excel Worksheet object in one slide to refresh its data each time that slide is displayed, showing the updated data in the looping presentation.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: do you have any initial code at the moment? (which is usually expected when asking here in SO). at the moment I would say it's possible to do so. But you provide too little information to help you.

Comment: I don't have any code yet.  This is something I am trying to set up for end-users to be able to do themselves, and so I wanted to know if there was functionality integrated into the Powerpoint GUI that would allow for this interactivity.  I understand that macros will likely be necessary, but I haven't written any yet as I'm not sure the angle to approach it from for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code to do the update is just one line:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).LinkFormat.Update
```

You can refer to both `Slides` and `Shapes` by index number or by name.  The above example updates the link for the 1st `Shape` object on the 2nd `Slide` object. You need to follow the steps below in order to make that code fire at the proper time.

From the Microsoft Office documentation:

> **How to: Use Events with the Application Object**
>
> To create an event handler for an event of the Application object, you
>   need to complete the following three steps:
>
> 1. Declare an object variable in a class module to respond to the events.
> 2. Write the specific event procedures.
> 3. Initialize the declared object from another module.
>
> Declare the Object Variable
>
> Before you can write procedures for the events of the Application
>   object, you must create a new class module and declare an object of
>   type Application with events. For example, assume that a new class
>   module is created and called EventClassModule. The new class module
>   contains the following code.
>
> VBA

```
 Public WithEvents App As Application
```

> Write the Event Procedures
>
> After the new object is declared with events, it appears in the Object
>   list in the class module, and you can write event procedures for the
>   new object. (When you select the new object in the Object list, the
>   valid events for that object are listed in the Procedure list.) Select
>   an event from the Procedure list; an empty procedure is added to the
>   class module.
>
> VBA

```
Private Sub App_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).LinkFormat.Update
End Sub
```

> Initializing the Declared Object
>
> Before the procedure will run, you must connect the declared object in
>   the class module (App in this example) with the Application object.
>   You can do this with the following code from any module.
>
> VBA

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule 
Sub InitializeApp()
   Set X.App = Application 
End Sub
```

> Run the InitializeApp procedure. After the procedure is run, the App
>   object in the class module points to the Microsoft Office PowerPoint
>   Application object, and the event procedures in the class module will
>   run when the events occur.

Comment: Are the Slide and Shape indexes not zero-based?

Comment: In Microsoft VBA, all collections are 1-based.  Even if you have your code declared as 0-based for the variables you create, the built-in VBA/Office object collections are 1-based.

Comment: True of VB as well.  Collections are always 1-based; arrays are not.